# How to understand "to which that"?

Tags: sentence-construction

The following quote is from a textbook about python.

> Notice that when f returns, even though the variable g no longer exists, the object of type function **to which that** name was once bound still exists.

I don't understand the meaning of "to which that". What's its effect on the whole sentence? Is it a kind of determiner clauses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "to which that".

It's

> [the object [[to which] [that name] was once bound]]] still exists.

So *that name* is a noun phrase, the subject of the relative clause *to which that name was once bound*. The relative clause  qualifies *the object*, which is the subject of the main clause.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So "the object to which that name was once bound still" can be paraphrased as "That name was once bound to the obect". Am I right?

Comment: In your version the name is the subject, but the real subject is 'the object'. You could paraphrase it as "The object which once had that name still exists".

Comment: I get it. Thanks a lot.